# How to write a MySQL function to extract JSONAttribute's value, based on name?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-function

I have a requirement that I need to write a mysql function which takes 'JSONText', 'color' as parameters and output based on the 'color'

```
[ 
  {
    "color":"red",
    "points":4
  },
  {
    "color": "Electric Blue",
    "points": 5
  }
 ]
```

So, my function would be

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION GetColorPoints(JSONParam Text, color VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS INT
 BEGIN
        **???** //WHAT SHOULD GO HERE??
 END$$
 DELIMITER;
```

So, if I call the function with inputs, it should give me points.

```
 SELECT GetColorPoints('[ {"color":"red", "points":4}, {"color": "Electric Blue", "points": 5} ]', 'Electric Blue') AS 'ColorPoints';
```

Comment: This is not a valid json object, are you sure the first and last curly brace "{" and "}" aren't suppose to be square brackets "[" and "]" ?

Comment: You are right @ggordon, I will correct the same in the question. thank you !

Comment: Which version of MysQL are you running?

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy enough to use MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `JSON_TABLE()`:

```
set @js = '[ { "color":"red", "points":4 }, { "color": "Electric Blue", "points": 5 } ]';
select points
from json_table(
    @js,
    '$[*]' columns(
        color varchar(50) path '$.color',
        points int path '$.points'
    )
) t
where color = 'red'
```

Comment: Hi @GMB. Thanks for reply. I'm currently using 5.7 version of mysql